# How to use aggregate functions in Amazon Dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

Am New to dynamodb I have a table in DynamoDB with more than 100k items in it. Also, this table gets refreshed frequently. On this table, I want to be able to do something similar to this in the relation database world: how i can get max value from the table.

Answer (score 33):

DynamoDB is a NoSQL database and therefore is very limited on how you can query data.  It is not possible to perform aggregations such as max value from a table by directly calling the DynamoDB API.  You will have to look to different tools and approaches to solve this problem.

There are a number of possible solutions you can consider:

**Perform A Table Scan**

With more than 100k items in your table this is likely a very bad idea.  A table scan will read through every single item and you can have application side logic identify the maximum value.  This really isn't a workable solution.

**Materialized Index in DynamoDB**

Depending on your use case you can use DynamoDB streams and a Lambda function to maintain an index in a separate DynamoDB table.  If your table is write only, no updates and no deletions, you could store the maximum in a separate table and as new records get inserted you can compare them and perform the necessary updates.

This approach is workable under some constrained circumstances, but is not a generalized solution.

**Perform Analytic using Amazon Redshift**

DynamoDB is not meant to do analytical operations such as maximum, while Redshift is a very powerful big data platform that can perform these types of calculations with ease.  Similar to the DynamoDB index, you can use DynamoDB streams to send data into Redshift as records get inserted to maintain a near real time copy of the table for analytical purposes.

If you are looking for more of an offline or analytical solution this is a good choice.

**Perform Analytics using Elasticsearch**

While DynamoDB is a powerful NoSQL solution with strong guarantees on data durability, Elasticsearch provides a very flexible querying method that allows for queries such as maximum and these aggregations can be sliced and diced on any attribute value in real time.  Similar to the above solutions you can use DynamoDB streams to send record inserts updates and deletions into the Elasticsearch index in real time.

If you want to stick with DynamoDB but need some additional querying capability, this is really a good option especially when using the AWS ES service which will fully manage an Elasticsearch cluster for you.  It is important to remember that Elasticsearch doesn't replace your DynamoDB table, it is just an easily searchable index of the same data.

**Just use a SQL Database**

The obvious solution is if you have SQL requirements then move from a NoSQL based system to a SQL based system.  AWS's RDS offering provides a managed solution.  While DynamoDB provides a lot of benefits, if your use case is pulling you towards a SQL solution the easiest thing to do may be to not fight it and just change solutions.

This is not to say that a SQL based solution or NoSQL based solution is better, there are pros and cons to each and those vary based on the specific use case, but it is definitely an option to consider.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB actually does have a MAX aggregate function: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.Querying.html

Comment: This is available through an Amazon EMR cluster connected to DynamoDB; it is not a feature available in DynamoDB itself. There's a [tutorial on setting that up](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.Tutorial.html) if you're not opposed to using a secondary service connected to your DynamoDB streams for aggregation queries.